# the function fgetc is not working properly

Tags: c, file, codeblocks

i'm testing the fgetc() function but it doesn't work properly (i have used this function befor so i know how it works)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int n;

    file = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
        if(file != NULL)
        {
            fputs("ab", file);
            printf("%c", fgetc(file));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

the output should be "a" but it's somthing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to read a file that has been opened for writting. You should write inside it, then close the file and reopen it for reading. This code will show what I am telling:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int main()
{


    FILE *fileRead, *fileWrite = NULL;
    int n;

    fileWrite = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
        if(fileWrite != NULL)
        {
            fputs("ab", fileWrite);
            fclose(fileWrite);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error");
        }

    // Open again the file for read
    fileRead = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    printf("%c", fgetc(fileRead));
    fclose(fileWrite);

    // End function
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The file is opened for both writing and reading but you need to `fseek` to the correct place in the file (here, the beginning). In particular, when switching between writing and reading you need to `fseek` or `fflush`.

> When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading
>   and writing are enabled (the file is said to be open for "update").
>   However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation
>   must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning
>   functions are fsetpos, fseek, and rewind. **When you switch from writing
>   to reading, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a
>   file positioning function**.

In any case, after writing to the file, the file pointer is in the wrong place to read what was just written.

So the code becomes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    file = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
    if(file != NULL) {
        fputs("ab", file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf("%c", fgetc(file));
        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        printf("error");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to continue writing to the file, you must `fseek` to its end.